# Why is mobile data so expensive in Cyprus?

Tags: economy, cyprus

A few days ago a relative who lives in Cyprus told me that mobile data is very expensive in Cyprus and that, as he is not living in a city, has to rely on an ADSL connection.

[This article](https://in-cyprus.com/mobile-data-in-cyprus-among-most-expensive-in-world/) confirms that Cyprus has the highest prices when it comes to mobile data.

As Internet feels more like a utility, it is very strange to have such high prices and I am wondering if this is caused by purely economical reasons or there are some political reasons as well.

**Question:** Why is mobile data so expensive in Cyprus?

Comment: Strange indeed. I have a UK sim on Three. Cyprus is part of their 'go roam' destinations meaning I can use my mobile data allowance in Cyprus. I currently pay £20 for an unlimited data allowance / month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR: The data is comparing apples to oranges

Under "Eastern Europe", the [quoted source](https://www.cable.co.uk/mobiles/worldwide-data-pricing/) explains:

> The presence of good network infrastructure throughout Eastern Europe helps the majority of countries to appear in the less expensive half of the table although none make it into the top 20 cheapest countries. The cheapest in the region is Poland with an average price per 1GB of $1.32, followed by Romania ($1.89) and Slovenia ($2.21).
>
> Greece’s well-documented economic problems are evident here, with mobile data prices in the country much more expensive than in any of its neighbours. Greece’s average price per 1GB of $32.71 puts it in the top 10 most expensive places in the world to buy mobile data and makes it easily the most expensive in Europe.

Assuming their [explanation for Greece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_government-debt_crisis) is correct, a [similar narrative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012%E2%80%9313_Cypriot_financial_crisis) might explain the situation in Cyprus (which is discussed, without any explanation, under "Near East").

That being said, I'm a bit suspicious that the explanation is correct. Switzerland and Malta, for instance, have it roughly as bad as Cyprus in their analysis.

I suspect the actual explanation has more to do with the fact that they're working with the *average prices of plans offered* by carriers rather than the *median price of plans payed* by consumers and businesses. To wit: in Greece, plan prices range from $2.37 to $106.85 per GB; in Cyprus, from $6.39 to $38.44 per GB; in Switzerland, from $8.30 to $49.79 per GB. So really it's just apples to oranges, garbage in garbage out.